# Reorder by specific factor in ggplot while filling by another

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Question:**

How do I create a descending bar chart (example below) in ggplot with the reorder based on the value of most recent year (blue, 2015)? I've tried altering the "FUN" option in reorder but didn't succeed. I did find some success with brackets, but when I applied them to the ggplot function they no longer worked.

[image: Example]

**Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.table(text = '
             facility  year value
             a  2012    5.066719095
             a  2013    6.199471839
             a  2014    4.522300089
             a  2015    4.92689046
             b  2012    4.165211821
             b  2013    3.542013367
             b  2014    3.323008647
             b  2015    2.775883861
             c  2012    6.68507118
             c  2013    7.590574237
             c  2014    8.035296346
             c  2015    6.248734117
             d  2012    7.318596505
             d  2013    5.556040733
             d  2014    4.706814181
             d  2015    3.395899009
             e  2012    7.032686869
             e  2013    6.714919
             e  2014    5.309100168
             e  2015    3.262501451
             f  2012    6.03334622
             f  2013    5.516842841
             f  2014    5.756024789
             f  2015    4.863173625
             g  2012    11.55785552
             g  2013    9.822368474
             g  2014    10.59960277
             g  2015    8.578816937
             h  2012    11.13759047
             h  2013    11.21849677
             h  2014    14.42275412
             h  2015    10.84418671
             i  2012    5.654301344
             i  2013    5.763859937
             i  2014    4.756596478
             i  2015    6.146759985
             j  2012    7.613800532
             j  2013    7.208221812
             j  2014    7.252485205
             j  2015    6.628703296
             k  2012    7.582829055
             k  2013    6.891288622
             k  2014    12.77089132
             k  2015    8.766426727
             l  2012    23.20319709
             l  2013    24.85267598
             l  2014    22.25478583
             l  2015    22.35339446
             m  2012    7.965939563
             m  2013    7.483046394
             m  2014    6.137859229
             m  2015    4.79897225
             n  2012    9.386677667
             n  2013    7.132884824
             n  2014    5.360270766
             n  2015    3.52531513
             ', header=T)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(reorder(facility, -value), value, fill=factor(year)),
           stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "grey", "grey", "dodgerblue"))
```

**What I tried:**

I did try both of the following outside of the ggplot function (which work)...

```
with(df, reorder(facility[year==2015], -value[year==2015])

subset(df[order(-df$value),], year==2015 )
```

...but, when I try them in the function it doesn't work because x and y end up with different lengths (which makes sense).

I did look up similar questions on SO, but none that I found address the specific issue of subsetting and reordering a factor, while filling by a another factor for use in ggplot .

I do also realize it would probably be better practice to facet by different years instead of showing them the way I am, but this is how my boss specified it. IMHO I think the mean is fine (default FUN in reorder), because clustering the years in this case visually implies the year to year variation must not be as important as the differences between factors (otherwise he would have specified the faceted version), but he insists on ordering bar groupings by the most recent year.

I am sure that I can manually hack something together, but it needs to be robust enough to use on a significantly larger data set that repeats this process over about 60 times, which is why I've come to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could refactor `facility` so that its levels are ordered by value for `year == 2015`:

```
df$facility <- factor(df$facility,levels=unique(df$facility)[order(df$value[df$year == 2015],decreasing = TRUE)])
```

We then plot with `x=facility` :

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(facility, value, fill=factor(year)),
           stat="identity", position="dodge", color="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "grey", "grey", "dodgerblue"))
```

output

[image]